# Cron Job / Twitter

Tags: php, mysql, apache, twitter, cron

I have a web app at mmatakedown.net. It's basically a social game, fantasy sports-esque, where you predict fight outcomes and score points and perks for getting them correct, with a leaderboard, etc.

Right now, I have a page I wrote to administer "results".  What I'd like to do is use cron job (or a better option?) to check twitter periodically (on the day of a fight card) and look for tweets that note the results of the fights. (from more trusted accounts to start, perhaps). For example, it might know that a card locked today, and that the deadline is passed, so it's time to start searching for results. If two fighters were named Brooks and Jones, for example, it might look for something like   Jones def. or Brooks def. to find out who the victor was, then search for something like "sub" or "ko" or "dec" to find out the method of victory.

Once it tallies a certain # of tweets to confirm the result, it would update the DB with the result, then set off a series of updates and notifications based on the result, who picked what, what scores were updated, any milestones reached, etc.

What would be the best approach for this?  I write the site w/ PHP/mysql/ajax/jquery presently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the *best* approach, but this functionality ought to be independent of your web application (i.e. the PHP/ajax/jquery code base).

It's a program that can run via cron, check the database for things that need to be updated, and then update the database appropriately.

You could run a cron job every hour or whatever you think is necessary in order to keep the database relatively up to date. Or you could get fancier I suppose.

I think cron is entirely appropriate though.

I have written Python programs that were invoked via cron, did some Twitter API calls, and updated a database. The application was quite different, but Python worked well for the task. It has built-in libraries for everything you'll need (e.g. JSON, http) except the MySQL access, but that's a quick package install.

One complication, you may start searching for tweets and find a few indicating the fight was over, but not enough to change your database. You will probably want a way to ensure that a subsequent invocation of the program has access to this information.

I think generally that when you write these offline batch updating scripts that you should have a table in your database for them to log to. For example, when did they start, how many tweets did they inspect, when did they exit, did they exit successfully, etc.

Comment: I agree about the log.  The idea is that I wouldn't need to intervene in the updates by manually choosing an outcome (which I have to do now, click a button which sends instructions to process a certain way).

The cron job would run constantly once the card deadline has been reached.  It will start with the preliminary bouts and, as they are updated, skip over them and go toward the main card / main event. If you are willing to share the code doing the twitter api calls, I'd appreciate it.

I was going to try to do it all w/ php, haven't considered python since I am not as familiar.

Comment: Disentangling the relevant code from the irrelevant code is more than I can take on now. The most relevant libraries are urllib and json. The most relevant calls are urllib.urlopen and json.loads. Once you have the json object it behaves like a dictionary. It's pretty straightforward.

The URL you use will be dependent upon what twitter API is most appropriate for you. Perhaps its the search api?

As far as cron goes, it will run a process periodically based upon the specification you give it. If you want your twitter client to run continually you do not need cron.